# Array.sort() compare function

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code I found to sort a list of numbers by ascending order is:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

I don't understand how the compare function works. What if you do arr.sort((a,b) => a+b)?

Comment: _..What if you do arr.sort((a,b) => a+b)?..._ Why don't you do that to see what happens?

Comment: It is very clearly explained in the documentation, try reading the function docs before posting a question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: a more explicit version of that function would be `(a,b) => { if (a < b) return -1; else if (a > b) return 1; else return 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

[The sort function uses the *sign* of the value returned by the comparator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

- Positive means A > B.
- Negative means A < B.
- Zero means A == B.

So `a - b` is just a neat shorthand which fulfills those cases.